# Failed to create component 'AxHost'

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, com

Добрый день, удалил и попытался снова добавить COM объект axMsRdpClient(до удаления он работал), но уже при повторной попытки добавить на форму возникла ошибка...

> Failed to create component 'AxHost'. The error message follows:
>   'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load on or
>   more of the requested types. Retreive the LoaderExceptions property
>   for more information.
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.DocumentDesigner.AxToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost
>   host)
>
> in
>   System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost
>   host, IDictionary defaultValues)
>
> in System.Drawing.Design.ToolboxItem.CreateComponents(IDesignerHost
>   host, IDictionary defaultValues)
>
> in
>   System.Windows.Forms.Design.OleDragDropHandler.CreateTool(ToolboxItem
>   tool, Control parent, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 width, Int32 height,
>   Boolean hasLocation, Boolean hasSize, ToolboxSnapDragDropEventArgs e)'

есть предположения как исправить этот глюк.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тоже сталкивался, пришлось вручную добавлять обе .dll в референс и на форму добавлять контрол из кодбехайнда. Либо создавать новый проект. Такое было замечено в VS 2013.

Comment: Проблему решил вашим методом спасибо, еще не большой вопрос, компонент axMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting1 работает при первом старте прекрасно, но вот при повторном соединение он отображает рабочий стол который становить не активным то есть нажать на ярлыки удаленного рабочего стола не получается, при этом при нажатии на axMsRdpClient7NotSafeForScripting1  слышно звуковое сообщения предупреждения схожее по звуку с попыткой смены модальных окон

Comment: Я с 7 не работал, только с 9 - там все в норме. Вообще ActiveX контрол от MS - это та еще солянка...

Comment: как ни странно на win8.1 все работает на Win7 нет, а если я добавляю Focus в код то он и первый раз перестаёт работать на win7